# Isn't $k\in \emptyset$ a contradictory statement?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

I've seen $k\in \emptyset$ written in the context of empty sum. I read, $k\in \emptyset$ as "$k$ is an element of the set which has no elements." To me, this sounds like a contradiction. If the empty set contains the element $k$ it is no longer empty.

Also, how do you arrive at the conclusion that because $k\in \emptyset$, $k$ does not exist? To say that $k$ is in the $\emptyset$ is a false statement, therefore nothing follows from it. If we want to say that $k$ does not exist we simply write $\neg \exists k$.

Since $k\in \emptyset$ is widely used there must be an explanation. Can you clarify how you rationalize the contradiction that empty set is not really empty? Does the set theory has its own logic where contradiction is legal?

---

**Edit**

I'm sorry it was not clear from the question that $k$ is a summation index and as such it cannot be a free variable. $k$ takes natural numbers as its values $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I think, therefore, answers claiming that $k\in \emptyset$ cannot be false because $k$ is a free variable are not acceptable. Please correct if I misunderstand.

Comment: The empty sum, $\sum_{k \in \varnothing} a_k = 0$, is mostly just a convention that works well in practice, just like $a^0 = 1$ for nonzero $a$.

Comment: There’s no contradiction here - when we write $k \in \varnothing$ we are not implying that there is something in the empty set. Quite the contrary. It is precisely because there’s no such $k$ that this sum is empty.

Comment: Also, the statement that that because $k \in \varnothing$, $k$ does not exist doesn’t really make much sense logically. The correct statement is that there exists no $k$ such that $k \in \varnothing$. Or, symbolically, $\neg \exists k (k \in \varnothing)$.

Comment: It could legitimately be a premise (a provisional what-if statement)  in a formal proof. As with any premise, it would eventually have to be discharged in that proof. You could, for example, prove $\forall k: [k \in \emptyset \implies P]$ for any proposition $P$, be it true or false.

Comment: The empty set, ∅, is a piece of notation. More formally, the empty set is defined as the unique y s.t. ∀x(x∈y ↔ x ≠ x), so x∈∅ ↔ x≠x.

Comment: @DavidGao It seems to me that you are changing the meaning of the symbol $\in$ for the case of $\emptyset$. I read $k\in S$ as "$k$ is an element of set $S$." I read $k\in E$ as "$k$ is an element of set E". And, naturally, I read $k \in \emptyset$ as "$k$ is an element of the empty set". How do you read $k \in \emptyset$ ? It seems that you are not reading $\in$ as "is element of" for the case of the empty set. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @zeynel $\in$ means “is an element of”. I’m not reading it any differently for the empty set. I’m simply saying there is no such $k$ such that it is an element of the empty set, which is precisely why that is an empty sum.

Comment: @MichaelCarey Am I reading your definition correctly? “For all $x$, such that, $x$ is an element of a set $y$, is equivalent to $x$ is not $x$”. I don’t understand why $x$ being an element of a set implies that $x$ is not $x$. And what does $x \neq x$ mean?

Comment: @zeynel It's a definition, we define the empty set so that the implication holds. Your reading is correct. It means that the elements of y, are all the sets not equal to themselves ( as there aren't any like that, we say y is empty, or the empty set). In general ( for sets)  a ≠ b means that a,b dont have the same elements. i.e. either there is some set c, which is in set a and not b, or vice versa.

Comment: @MichaelCarey It looks like you pretend not to know that $y$ is the empty set, then you pretend not to know that there are no sets which are not equal to themselves and then you pretend to realize that $y$ really was $\emptyset$. Why? What’s wrong with the definition of the empty set as the set which has no elements? Isn’t this definition simpler?

Comment: @zeynel " the set which has no elements" is the naive definition for the empty set, and is suitable for some things. But, there are limitations to such a methodology. How do we know such a set exists? How do we prove things about such a set? By working with a more formal language and framework- we can extend what can be proven formally, via mathematical proof. The Mathematical language of Set Theory only has $\in$, =, $\exists$,$\neg$ as official symbols, along with variables to quantify over. So the definition has to be in terms of those characters.

Comment: We could add as an axiom that $\exists$y$\forall$x($\neg$(x$\in$y)) - Such a y is called the empty set. Which is fine, but then one is just assuming the empty set exists, they haven't constructed it. The first definition, is better in the sense that it constructs an object with the property that we want ( it is empty) rather than just assuming the existence of such an object satisfying some property.

Comment: *parenthesis are also part of the language

Comment: @MichaelCarey Thanks for the explanation. I could not decipher your first definition of the empty set but in the latest one you wrote as an axiom, does the negation symbol $\neg$ makes the statement $x\in y$ a false statement? If so we would be drawing conclusions from falsity, it seems to me. Can you write, if you get the time, your first definition as an answer using less confusing notation including more details?

Comment: @DavidGao I think there are two issues here. The convention is to write $0$ as a placeholder for the non-existent summands. This is a convention like using $0$ as a placeholder in our place-value number system. This is understandable.

Comment: @DavidGao The other issue is writing the summation index $k$ as an element of the empty set under the summation sign. First, $k$ is an arithmetic term, it is not a logical term. Arithmetic terms start to exist when they are written and stop to exist when they are removed. Second, since $k\in \emptyset$ is a false statement it voids the summation. ($k\notin \emptyset$ = True, $k \in \emptyset$ = False). So, $k\in \emptyset$ says: "This summation does not exist." The summation sign says "this is a summation" but its index says "this is not a summation." This appears to be an abuse of notation.

Comment: @zeynel It’s more that 0 is used as a placeholder when summing things - since 0 is the additive identity (that is, $0 + x = x$ for all $x$) but not in general. For example, an empty product would usually be 1, since 1 is the multiplicative identity (that is, $1 \times x = x$ for all $x$).

Comment: @zeynel From a purely mathematical point of view, there is no such distinction as “arithmetic term” and “logical term”. It’s just a variable, which has a precise definition in terms of formal logic. As to the “existence” of such terms, that’s a philosophical question more than a mathematical one. Since this is already becoming more complicated than it should have been, I’d rather not delve any deeper into the philosophy of mathematics.

Comment: For your second point, from the point of view of formal logic (which is what people in mathematics follow when they, for example, write down an empty sum), it’s incorrect to say $k \in \varnothing$ is false. $k$ is a free variable in this formula, so it doesn’t have a truth value unless you substitute $k$ with some specific object. This is already mentioned by Jackozee in their answer. In particular, such an index does not mean “this is not a summation”, whatever that even means. But I wouldn’t deny it is an abuse of notation. Again, it’s really just a convention that is convenient in practice

Comment: @DavidGao "$k$ is a free variable in this formula." In this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples, in the first example, they seem to say that the upper index $n$ is the free variable and the lower index, the summation index, $k$ is the bound variable. So, in our case, in $k\in \emptyset$, $k$ is the summation index. If so, our $k$ is not supposed to be a free variable. Do I understand this correctly? Any comments?

Comment: There are two different issues here: Once you write the summation down, namely some $\sum_{k \in \varnothing} a_k$, then indeed $k$ is a bound variable. That doesn't mean that if you *just write down* $k \in \varnothing$, $k$ is still a bound variable. It is the summation symbol that makes $k$ a bound variable, so to speak. This is why $\sum_{k \in \varnothing} a_k$ has a specific (arithmetic) value, namely 0, but $k \in \varnothing$, by itself, does not possess such a (logical) value...

Comment: I should further note that, even if you write down $\sum_{k \in \varnothing} a_k$, you cannot then say $k \in \varnothing$ is false. The fact that in a larger formula $k$ is bound does not imply in a sub-formula it still remains bound. (The above is already an example. Another example already mentioned: in $\forall x, \neg x \in \varnothing$, $x$ is bound, but in $\neg x \in \varnothing$, it is not.) Whether a variable is bound or not depend on the formula in which it appears, it is not a intrinsic property of the letter $k$ you wrote down.

Comment: @DanChristensen Why do you say $k\in \emptyset$ is a premise? To me it looks like a definite declaration of a fact. I see that the verb is the $\in$ symbol and it declares $k$ to be an element of a set. The symbol $\in$ does not say $k$ may be an element of a set depending on some proof, it says $k$ **is** an element of a set. Why are we questioning the authority of the symbol $\in$ ?

Comment: @zeynel I said it COULD legitimately be a premise in a proof. A premise need not be true. You COULD start a proof with the premise, $k\in \emptyset$.

Comment: @DavidGao (From your comment on Dec. 29): "$0$ is used as a placeholder when summing things." What is $0$ placeholding for?

Answer (score 4):

The formula
$$k\in\emptyset \tag1$$
is a predicate with a free variable $k$. It is still *not* true *nor* false, because you still have not said what $k$ is. Please note that this predicate is **not** saying that there exists $k$ with $k\in\emptyset$. That formula would be
$$\exists k,\ \ k\in\emptyset \tag 2$$
which indeed *has the value false*. This is probably what you have in mind.

Again, the predicate $(1)$ is a formula with a free variable, so it *doesn't have a truth value*, while the proposition $(2)$ *has the value false*.
On the other hand, what you observe is that there cannot be a $k$ for which formula $(1)$ has the value truth. This sentence is captured by the formula
$$\forall k, \ \ \neg(k\in \emptyset). \tag 3$$
which *has the value true*.

Comment: “predicate with a free variable k” How do we know this is a predicate? We know that $k$ is a summation index that can take natural numbers as its values. Also, $k$ is an arithmetic term, it’s not a logic term. Arithmetic terms start to exist when you write them down and stop existing when you remove them. So, there is no question that $k$ here exists.

Comment: Also, in this site https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Empty_Set they state that "$x \in \emptyset$ is false, whatever $x$ is." Can you comment on this?

Comment: The meaning of that statement in wiki, if you want to be formal, is $\forall x, \neg x \in \varnothing$, that is not the same as saying $x \in \varnothing$ on itself is false. (It’s really better for this discussion if you find a book on first-order logic and model theory and see how truth value is formally defined there. Otherwise everyone here seems to be just running around in circles with you.)

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two seperate questions:

On the notation for summations and specifically the empty sum, we read:

$$\sum_{k \in X}a_k$$
As the sum of all $a_k$ such that $k \in X$. For the empty sum, we would read:
$$\sum_{k \in \emptyset}a_k$$
As the sum of all $a_k$ such that $k \in \emptyset$, which (you are correct) there are none. Which is why the empty sum evaluates to $0$, because we are summing nothing. This is simply a matter of notation and how to read summations, it is not a logical argument, no worries!

On your question about contradictions you write two things:

> How do you arrive at the conclusion that because $k \in \emptyset$, $k$ does not exist? To say that $k$ is in the $\emptyset$ is a false statement, therefore nothing follows from it.

Your second statement is incorrect. If we can come to the conclusion that a false statement, namely $k \in \emptyset$, is true, then we can come to the conclusion that any other false statement is also true, which we know is not correct. Therefore, we know our original statement was incorrect, and hence there are no $k \in \emptyset$. This is the concept known as the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) and it relies around the idea that (If $F$ is a false statement). Using this concept, when we come to a statement that we know is false, we can then deduce that our original assumption was false. For example, if we assume $A$ to be true then:

$$A \Rightarrow B \Rightarrow C \Rightarrow F$$
Would point us to the idea that $A$ is false, since we know that $F$ is false and when we assume $A$ to be true $F$ evaluates to true. In proofs we state that this is contradiction, since $F$ should be true based on our work but we know it is false.

To arrive at the conclusion (with a contradiction) that $(k \in \emptyset) \Rightarrow \neg \exists k$, we can do the following: First, we assume that there exists a $k$ such that $k \in \emptyset$. Then, since $\emptyset \subset A$ for any set $A$, $k \in A$. But the set $A = \{b\}$ does not contain $k$, hence this is a contradiction and thus there does not exist a $k$ such that $k \in \emptyset$. Or any other argument where you can arrive at a contradiction that is shorter or longer than mine. A much easier proof, is just to say: by definition $\neg \exists k (k \in\emptyset)$.

Comment: Your proof by contradiction can be much shorter I think: "we assume that there exists a $k$ such that $k\in \emptyset$ QED :) Since empty set is empty by definition this statement must be false.

Comment: I think this is the problematic satetement for me: "the empty sum evaluates to $0$, because we are summing nothing." We don't have summands to evaluate so nothing is evaluated. Can you evaluate the following sum: No, you cannot because there is nothing there. Nothing does not evaluate to $0$. So I agree that, as you say, equating summation without summands to $0$ is a notational convention. So $0$ in $\sum_{k\in \emptyset} a_k = 0$ is only a placeholder for the non-existent summands.

Comment: @zeynel if you assume something is true saying well it's not true actually is kind of a silly proof by contradiction and is more of a direct proof, so in the spirit of an actual contradiction I think that works. Also for $k \in \emptyset$ its a heuristic, there is no like definitional or rigorous explanation for notation, but the heuristic helps one understand why we have the notation.

Comment: "$k\in \varnothing$ is a heuristic..." I don't agree. $k\in \varnothing$ or in its more general form, $x\in y$ is a declarative sentence. It says: "element is an element of set." When we replace "set" with "empty set" we are knowingly making a false statement because we know that the set with no elements has no elements: "element is an element of the set with no elements" is a classic self-referential contradiction.

Comment: The element says to the set "I'm your element" and set replies, "No, you are not my element" and contradiction ensues. So, $x\in \varnothing$ is a contradiction that has the same form as "This is not a sentence."

Comment: @zeynel yes you’re reasoning is the point as to why it’s a heuristic notation, and not saying x is actually in the empty set. You’ve said assume this isn’t notation, then we have a contradiction. But instead of concluding it must be notational, you then argue it simply must be a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

What is a contradiction in Mathematical Logic?

Definition: A sentence is called a contradiction if its truth table only has false values.

Where a sentence is a formula with no free variables.

The formula x$\in$$\emptyset$ needs to unraveled, as $\emptyset$ is a defined term.

formally, x$\in$$\emptyset$ is shorthand for x$\in$y $\wedge$ $\forall$w$\in$y(w ≠ w)

Note: The same unraveling needs to be done with the empty sum in order to assess if it is a contradiction or not. The standard notation is just a shorhand for a longer formula, don't focuse on the syntax for the shorthand.

So x, is a free variable ( not bound by a quantifier) and so it doesn't make sense to talk about if it's a contradiction because it isn't even a sentence.

If we wanted to consider the sentence:

$\exists$x$\exists$y(x$\in$y $\wedge$ $\forall$w$\in$y(w ≠ w))

Then we could say that such a sentence is a contradiction

I usually see x$\in$$\emptyset$ as a premise in a vacuously true implication.

For example, Let's Prove $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set.

Definition: X $\subset$ Y $\iff$ $\forall$z(z$\in$X $\rightarrow$ z$\in$Y)

So we prove $\forall$z(z$\in$$\emptyset$ $\rightarrow$ z$\in$Y)

Proof: Let Y be a set.

Let $z_0$ be arbitrarily chosen.

Then

$z_0$$\in$$\emptyset$ $\rightarrow$$z_0$$\in$Y

Is true as the premise is false.

Thus $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm sorry that it was not clear that $k$ is a summation index taking natural numbers as its values so $k$ is not a free variable. (I updated the question.)

Comment: But even if $k$ were to be a free variable $k\in \emptyset$ would still be false because by definition, $\neg\exists k : k\in \emptyset$ = False (You wrote a version of this statement and said it was false.) Or equivalently, $\exists k : k\notin \emptyset$ = True

Comment: We know that $\emptyset$ has no elements and that nothing in the entire universe, including free variables, can be an element of the set with no elements. So, what is the point of writing $k\in \emptyset$ when we know that by definition this $k$ whether or not a free variable cannot be a member of the empty set?

Comment: I don't know the history of the notation, for the empty summation. Sorry! I wish I knew the answer. It's just a piece of notation, not a logical claim. You can just consider it a symbol which is defined to be equal to 0.  There isn't any deeper logic going on.

Comment: I finally understood your definition of empty set on your Dec. 25 comment :) I was reading $\iff$ incorrectly. When I read it as "for all $x$ such that $x$ is an element of $y$ if and only if $x$ equals not $x$," it all made sense. Since there is no $x$ that equals not-$x$, we say that $y$ is an empty set. But for the purpose of this question what matters is that $k$, whatever $k$ is, cannot be a member of the empty set by definition. It doesn't matter if $k$ is bound or unbound.

Comment: @zeynel yes!! that is exactly what I meant by the definition I gave earlier!! :)  Very Good!

Comment: From your comment on Dec. 28: $\exists y \forall x(\neg(x\in y))$ is the same as $\exists y \forall x : \neg(x\in y)$ right?

Comment: @zeynel Yes! Same thing.

Comment: Thanks. On your Dec. 28 comment, you listed the official symbols of the set theory. I assume you meant to include $\forall$ as well. But I noticed that $\in$ is a symbol of the set theory but apparently not a symbol of the first order logic. $k\in \varnothing$ is a simple declarative sentence so it should belong to propositional logic. I'm trying to understand why people automatically classified $k\in \varnothing$ as belonging to FOL.

Comment: Officially, $\in$ is not a symbol of FOL, you need some set theory added in. Its a bit lazy to just say FOL and not specify more, ZFC, Set Theory is a First Order Theory - with elementhood added in, which is probably why they say that. The reason I didn't include $\forall$x,$\rightarrow$... etc is because it is unnescesary, They are useful symbols but Don't need to be part of the base language. Since $\forall$x($\phi$) is equivalent to $\neg$($\exists$x($\neg$$\phi$)). Note: Earlier I did forget $\wedge$, as a symbol. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand this statement: $x\in \varnothing \wedge \forall w \in y (w \neq w)$. Here $\wedge$ means "conjuction" right? But $k\in \varnothing$ or more generally, $x\in y$, is a declarative sentence that states a fact: "$x$ is an element of $y$". How can a declarative sentence be in conjuction with something else? As far I know, for conjuction we need two sets. Does $\wedge$ have another meaning that I don't know?

Comment: Here, $\wedge$ is also conjunction. But rather than between two sets it's between two formula. If $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are two well formed formula of LST then $\phi$ $\wedge$ $\varphi$ is also a formula of the language of set theory, and is interpreted to mean $\phi$ AND $\varphi$. Also did you mean to write: x$\in$y $\wedge$ $\forall$w$\in$y(w $\neq$ w) ? The interpretation here is: x is an element of y AND  y is the empty set. But in order to say y is the empty set using a formula of LST, we say every element of y is not equal to itself.